# Work around for issue multiple user models with devise_token_auth and active_model_serializers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, token, active-model-serializers

The combination of multiple user models (User, Admin, and Master) with devise_token_auth does not successfully set the Response Headers (uid, token, etc.) upon login with non "User" models (Admin and Master); however, User model works.

The cause looks to be the default serialization_scope (:current_user) in active_model_serializers/lib/action_controller/serialization.rb:18.

Is there a way to set the serialization_scope, or do I need to override the controllers?

Environment:

- Rails 4.2.6
- AMS 10.3
- devise_token_auth 1.38

Answer (score 6):

My current work around was to set the scope in an overridden controller like below. This feels brittle, but it works

```
class Overrides::Master::SessionsController < DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController

  protected
    def render_create_success
      render json: {
       data: resource_data(resource_json: @resource.token_validation_response)
      }, scope: :current_master
    end
end
```